# Requiring a Geometrical proof

Tags: geometry, circles

In the figure, ABCD is a square circumscribing a circle ($\pi_1$) whose center is E, the point of intersection of the diagonals AC and BD. With A as center, AB as radius, sector ABD is drawn cutting $\pi_1$ at G (and also at G').

[image]

I have proved CG = CE in  ([problem #994185](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994185/how-to-prove-that-the-problem-cannot-be-solved-by-the-four-arithmetic-operations/1070181#1070181)) by analytic method. The question is :- can this fact be proven by Geometrical method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the cosine theorem (law of cosines) in $\triangle AEG$ and calculate $\cos \theta$ ($\theta$ is the measure of angle $AEG$).

Use the cosine theorem again in $\triangle GEC$, and calculate $GC$.

Recall that $-\cos \theta = \cos (\pi- \theta)$.

Comment: Yes and thank you. Should have thought of that.